# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available

Tags: web3js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Deploy a Remix Contract</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Ethereum Secret Messenger</h1>
        <hr>

        <label for="message">This site writes a secret message to the Ethereum
            blockchain!</label>
        <input id="userInput" type="text">

        <button type="button" id="setMessageButton" onclick="setMessage()">Set secret message</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        // Connect a the web3 provider
        if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
            web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
        } else {
            web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/0f3d9f30356e48c7b048c0b6a6c8ceae"));
        }

        // Set a default account
        web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
        var abi = [
    {
        "constant": false,
        "inputs": [
            {
                "name": "x",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "name": "setMessage",
        "outputs": [],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "function"
    },
    {
        "constant": true,
        "inputs": [],
        "name": "getMessage",
        "outputs": [
            {
                "name": "",
                "type": "string"
            }
        ],
        "payable": false,
        "stateMutability": "view",
        "type": "function"
    }
]
        // Get the contract address
        var RemixContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, '0x633566E3C7e08f660987719841F77c0faa85bFbF');

        const setMessage = ()=>{
            RemixContract.methods.setMessage(document.getElementById("userInput").value).send({from:'0x20f2E66DA9315D447b22059F154ed1E016d41369'});
            console.log(document.getElementById("userInput").value)
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am connecting to Rinkeby test blockchain using infura and deployed the below contract using remix and I injected my account using web3 with metamask.

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Message {
    string myMessage;

    function setMessage(string x) public {
        myMessage = x;
    }

    function getMessage() public view returns (string) {
        return myMessage;
    }
}
```

when i send the message in my html file i get this error `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available`

The code was working when i used in local blockchain by Ganache but when i transferred to Rinkeby i get this error please help guys

Please note that I am new to BlockChain and I just want to send a transaction containing only message using the function in the smart contract. Please tell me what to change in order for making it works.

Comment: Infura doesn't support `eth.sendTransaction`. You have to sign the transaction yourself and send them using `eth.sendSignedTransaction`. You can automate it using a provider that signs transactions like [@truffle/hdwallet-provider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider) or a wallet like metamask.

Comment: I am new to Blockchain, my purpose is to send a simple message to the blockchain, and I do not know where to use the eth.sendSignedTranscation, should I use it instead of send()?

Comment: Metamask has changed the way it should be initialized. Check their documentation https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html.

Comment: Hey @нεx did you able to resolve it?